# Checking if a number occurs in a list of numbers

Tags: scheme

Write a procedure called `direct-num-occurs`? that checks whether a number occurs in a list of numbers. Examples:

```
> (direct-num-occurs? 1 '(2 3 1 4))
;=> #t
```

```
> (direct-num-occurs? 1 '(2 3 5 4))
;=> #f
```

This is what I tried:

```
(define direct-num-occurs?
  (lambda (num ws)
    (cond
      [(null? ws) #f]
      [(equal? num (car ws)) #t]
      [else (direct-num-occurs? (cdr ws) num)])))
```

But I'm getting an error that says expected a pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, you're re-implementing the [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._member%29%29) procedure:

```
(define (direct-num-occurs? n lst)
  (if (member n lst) #t #f))
```

... But I guess you're trying to write it from scratch. The implementation shown is basically correct, *except* that you passed the arguments in the wrong order in the last line. This should fix it:

```
(define direct-num-occurs?
  (lambda (num ws)
    (cond
      [(null? ws) #f]
      [(equal? num (car ws)) #t]
      [else (direct-num-occurs? num (cdr ws))])))
```

Of course, it works as expected:

```
(direct-num-occurs? 1 '(2 3 1 4))
=> #t

(direct-num-occurs? 1 '(2 3 5 4))
=> #f
```

Comment: ugh stupid stupid mistake, and yeah we were told to do it from scratch because we are learning the cond function. Thank you!

Comment: @NathanCurtis that's all right :) but you should _test_ your procedures more carefully before posting a question, ok?